# Can I use CATPCA to reduce the amount of variables in a multinominal logistics regression?

Tags: regression, pca, spss, factor-analysis, multinomial-logit

Dear to whom it may concern.

I am analyzing survey data and I have one dependent nominal variable and 11 nominal independent variables for the multinominal logistics regression.

I just wanted to find the best way to reduce the amount of independent variables in the multi-nominal logistics regression?

Can I use CATPCA for this reduction?
if not what approach or method do I take.

a note that I am restricted to using SPSS.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use not CatPca but Categorical regression (CatReg) also available in spss (in Regression section). Actually, CatReg is a particular case of Categorical Discriminant analysis.

Comment: i read it as "captcha" for a moment.

Comment: Can I reduce the amount of independent variables in the regression model using CatReg, also is CatReg used with the multinominal logit regression model or instead of it?                Many thanks btw